# Highlights Panel in a custom Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, highlights-panel

I'm wondering whether I could use "Highlights Panel Component" inside my custom component. is there some sort of tag that i can use it on my view or something.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Actually I did some search and reached that I will write it from scratch using Lightening card https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:card/example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I did some research and reached that I will write it from scratch using Lightning card component.Please check [this link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:card/example)